# Spaces in URLs?

Tags: http, url, standards

[w3fools](http://w3fools.com) claims that URLs can contain spaces: http://w3fools.com/#html_urlencode

Is this true? How can a URL contain an un-encoded space?

I'm under the impression the [request line of an HTTP Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message) uses a space as a delimiter, being formatted as `{the method}{space}{the path}{space}{the protocol}`:

```
GET /index.html http/1.1
```

Therefore how can a URL contain a space? If it can, where did the practice of replacing spaces with `+` come from?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

A URL must not contain a literal space. It must either be encoded using the [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) or a different encoding that uses [URL-safe characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/1547940#1547940) (like [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) that uses `+` instead of `%20` for spaces).

But whether the statement is right or wrong depends on the interpretation: Syntactically, a URI must not contain a literal space and it must be encoded; semantically, a `%20` is not a space (obviously) but it *represents* a space.

Comment: So... is their criticism inaccurate?

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: That depends on how you interpret it: Syntactically, a URI must not contain a literal space and it must be encoded; semantically, a `%20` is not a space (obviously) but it represents a space.

Comment: Ya, that's the best interpretation I can come up with, too.

Comment: And +1000000 for citing a source. This question wasn't about technology but rather about credibility and misinformation, yet it look all of 2 minutes to have 3 other unjustified, unreferenced and unproven answers which could just as easily be personal opinions. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

They are indeed fools. If you look at [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) Appendix A, you will see that "space" is simply not mentioned anywhere in the grammar for defining a URL. Since it's not mentioned anywhere in the grammar, the only way to encode a space is with percent-encoding (`%20`).

In fact, the RFC even states that spaces are delimiters and should be ignored:

> In some cases, extra whitespace (spaces, line-breaks, tabs, etc.) may
>      have to be added to break a long URI across lines.  The whitespace
>      should be ignored when the URI is extracted.

and

> For robustness, software that accepts user-typed URI should attempt
>      to recognize and strip both delimiters and embedded whitespace.

Curiously, the use of `+` as an encoding for space isn't mentioned in the RFC, although it is reserved as a sub-delimeter. I suspect that its use is either just convention or covered by a different RFC (possibly HTTP).

Comment: The character `+` is not translated into a space (or vice versa) by any part of the HTTP request process in the general case.  It is, however, translated into a space when encountered as the value of a parameter in an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" query string, and often preferred by browser software over `%20`, for the sake of brevity, when such query strings are appended to request URIs. Of course, the HTTP server may also choose to treat `+` as equivalent to space within URI paths, but that's not specified by the standard.

Comment: However! The same standard, on the same page, also mentions: "Using <> angle brackets around each URI is especially recommended as a delimiting style for a reference that contains embedded whitespace."  So how about that?

Answer (score 16):

Spaces are simply replaced by "%20" like :

http://www.example.com/my%20beautiful%20page

Comment: Edited the question to specify un-encoded space.

Comment: Clicking on the link gives a 400 page. I think you're missing a `20` after your second `%`.

Comment: I tried this with a `DELETE` `curl` API and it worked. Separating strings by `+` however did not.

Answer (score 4):

The information there is I think partially correct:

> That's not true. An URL can use spaces. Nothing defines that a space is replaced with a + sign.

As you noted, an URL can NOT use spaces. The HTTP request would get screwed over. I'm not sure where the `+` is defined, though `%20` is standard.