# Find URL in String

Tags: java, regex, string, url

hi im tring to find a URL in a string, i founded many topics about this using regex but i have a problem. Using this pattern:

```
String regex = "\\b(((ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/|~\\/|\\/)|www.)" + 
            "(\\w+:\\w+@)?(([-\\w]+\\.)+(com|org|net|gov" + 
            "|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum" + 
            "|travel|[a-z]{2}))(:[\\d]{1,5})?" + 
            "(((\\/([-\\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})+)+|\\/)+|\\?|#)?" + 
            "((\\?([-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" +
            "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)" + 
            "(&(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" + 
            "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)*)*" + 
            "(#([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)?\\b";
```

Its works pretty well in most of pages, but i have an issue with other. For example:

[http://hello.com/hello world](http://hello.com/hello%20world)

returns

http://hello.com/hello

The problems is that space.

Anyone have a nice pattern that solve this?

Thanks.

EDIT:: this is my code

```
private ArrayList<String> pullLinks(String text) {
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();

    String regex = "\\b(((ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/|~\\/|\\/)|www.)" + 
            "(\\w+:\\w+@)?(([-\\w]+\\.)+(com|org|net|gov" + 
            "|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum" + 
            "|travel|[a-z]{2}))(:[\\d]{1,5})?" + 
            "(((\\/([-\\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})+)+|\\/)+|\\?|#)?" + 
            "((\\?([-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" +
            "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)" + 
            "(&(?:[-\\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\\d{2}])+=?" + 
            "([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)*)*" + 
            "(#([-\\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\\d]{2})*)?\\b";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while(m.find()) {
    String urlStr = m.group();
    if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")"))
    {
    urlStr = urlStr.substring(1, urlStr.length() - 1);
    }
    links.add(urlStr);
    }
    return links;
    }
```

Comment: Offtopic: There are more top level TLDs with more that 2 letters, that those you have listed. Check [Wikipedia list of TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). Also your regexp will miss URLs written like this: `example.com`.

Comment: Offtopic, but here's a good pattern for matching URLs, explained row by row: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed in URLs (they need to be replaced by `%20`). See for instance the answer to this question:

- [Spaces in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls)

If you allow URLs to include spaces anyway, then how would you interpret for instance `http://www.google.com/ig is a nice webpage`? Clearly the part after `/ig` should not be included!

Comment: so there isn't any way to detect Urls with %20?

Comment: Sure there is. The expression you have already does. Look for instance at `%[a-f\\d]{2}` (means `%` followed by `{2}` characters that are in range `a-f` or are digits).

Comment: this is not working for me. Edit question with my code. thanks

Comment: (http://hello.com/hello world)

returns

http://hello.com/hello    should return http://hello.com/hello%20world

Comment: @AlexxPerez, what should ("google.com/ig is a nice website") return?

Comment: sry iknow what you mean. but my URL always finish with .jpg  ("http://google.com/ig is a nice website.jpg")  return http://google.com/ig%20is%20a%20nice%20website.jpg     sry

Comment: Then adding the following to your expression: `regex = "(" + regex + ").*?\\.jpg"` to your regular expression.

Comment: just a thing more please. how can i select until the first .jpg??

Answer (score 0):

Space is not a valid URL character.

Also, if you don't use whitespace as your terminator how are you going to find the end of the URL?

Your regex is also failing to account for other top level domains (like .int). I'm not actually sure why it is looking for specific TLDs at all as they are not required to form a valid URL.

Comment: its not a problem for me that fails with .int or others. my URL always will be: http://something.es/some some.jpg