# How to disable HTML URL escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, escaping

I have a Rails application that lists different teams in a list on one the views. The teams are links and used in the URL, for example `localhost:3000/teams/chelsea` shows "chelsea".

If I have a team called `man utd` when I click the link it escapes all the spaces so the URL is like:

```
localhost:3000/teams/<script>man%20utd
```

but I just it want it to be

```
localhost:3000/teams/<script>man utd
```

This is my code:

```
   <a href="/<%= team["name"].html_safe %>"><%= team["name"] %></a>
```

I tried using `html_safe` after reading other questions and also `raw` but have had no luck with them.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: That's not HTML escaping, that's URL encoding. You can't put a space in a URL. Rails should be able to manage for static URLs, can you post  config/routes.rb

Comment: What Slicedpan says is correct. This has nothing to do with Ruby or Rails. Your browser encodes the URL automatically and there is nothing you can do to prevent that.

Comment: It also changes < to /%3 what is the best way to handle this? Should I stop the user enter spaces and < for the team name on the client side? or which way would be more correct?

Comment: Best practice is to not use URLs that contain spaces or other characters that require escaping. User input validation is a whole different question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put any spaces in your URLs - do it as "man-utd" instead. See [Spaces in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls)

There are also more Rails-y ways to write out your links. If your teams are a database model I'd write them out as:

```
<% @teams.each do |team| %>
   <%= link_to team.name, team %>
<% end %>
```

But that will link to /teams/1 and teams/2 etc and you'll have to put in a specific route to map /teams/chelsea to /teams/1.

If you've just done them as separate views for man utd and chelsea then do:

```
<%= link_to 'Man Utd', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'man-utd' %>
<%= link_to 'Chelsea', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'chelsea' %>
```