# play remote audio files from server having spaces in name

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium

am using titanium Appcelerator for an IOS app.
am currently playing audio files which are on my web server.
All files are being played but only those files are not playing which are having spaces in url name.
For example

```
url=http://www.myweb.com/words/play mine.mp3
```

this url has space in it i.e play mine,so it is not playing.
but a url with no space is playing like.

```
url2=http://www.myweb.com/words/mine.mp3
```

please help!
regards,
Tashen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spaces in URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encode that part of the URL:

```
url = "http://www.myweb.com/words/" + encodeURIComponent("play mine.mp3");
```