# Space between http url in java

Tags: java

This code working fine

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8090/Servlet/ServletFirst?to=1234&from=567&text=testtest");
```

If i use space between parameter value. It throws exception

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8090/Servlet/ServletFirst?to=1234&from=567&textParam=test test");
```

space between test test throws error. How to resolve?

Comment: `%20`............?  I think there's an URL encoder laying around somewhere...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must URL encode the parameter in your URL; use `%20` instead of the space.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8090/Servlet/ServletFirst?to=1234&from=567&textParam=test%20test");
```

Java has a class to do do URL encoding for you, `URLEncoder`:

```
String param = "test test";
String enc = URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");

String url = "http://...&textParam=" + enc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `%20` to represent a space.

This is all part of the URL encoding: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

So you would want:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8090/Servlet/ServletFirst?to=1234&from=567&text=test%20test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
URLEncoder.encode("test test","UTF-8")
```

So change your code to

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8090/Servlet/ServletFirst?to=1234&from=567&textParam="+URLEncoder.encode("test test","UTF-8"));
```

**Note** *Don't `Encode` Whole url*

```
URLEncoder.encode("http://...test"); // its Wrong because it will also encode the // in http://
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `%20` to indicate space in the URL, as space is not an allowed character. See [the Wikipedia entry for character data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding#Character_data) in a URL.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
    "http://localhost:8090/Servlet/ServletFirst?to=1234&from=567&textParam=test%20test");
```