# URLConnection does not send full URL (java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server)

Tags: java

i call a URL using Java from URLConnection

```
http://192.168.2.107/cgi-bin/mediaFileFind.cgi?action=findFile&object=27891384&condition.Channel=0&conditon.Dir[0]="/mnt/sd"&condition.StartTime=2014-8-1 00:00:00&condition.EndTime=2014-8-31 23:59:59
```

but when i am capture HTTP transmission using wire-shark. wire-shark capture following URL

```
Full request URI: http://192.168.2.107/cgi-bin/mediaFileFind.cgi?action=findFile&object=28048800&condition.Channel=0&conditon.Dir[0]="/mnt/sd"&condition.StartTime=2014-8-1
```

that's mean the data loss on URL 
my full URL is does not send to server that's why error is generating my java Code is

```
 public String intilizeObject(String IP, String user, String pass, String objectID, String dir, String startTime, String endTime) {

        String result = "";
        try {
            String URL = "http://" + IP + "/cgi-bin/mediaFileFind.cgi?action=findFile&object=" + objectID + "&condition.Channel=0&conditon.Dir[0]=\"" + dir + "\"&condition.StartTime=" + startTime + "&condition.EndTime=" + endTime;           
            String authString = user + ":" + pass;
            byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
            String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
            URL url = new URL(URL);
            System.out.println(url);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int numCharsRead;
            char[] charArray = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
            }
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = e.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Help me i am not able to get what is happening there

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Edit it into your question.

Comment: There is a space between 2014-8-1 and 23:59:59 (2014-8-31 23:59:59). That may cause the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try URL-encoding the `startTime` and `endTime` parameters.

```
String URL = "http://" + IP + "/cgi-bin/mediaFileFind.cgi?action=findFile&object=" +
             objectID + "&condition.Channel=0&conditon.Dir[0]=\"" + dir +
             "\"&condition.StartTime=" + URLEncoder.encode(startTime, "UTF-8") +
             "&condition.EndTime=" + URLEncoder.encode(endTime, "UTF-8");
```

Both these parameters contain spaces in them, and in a URL spaces should be represented as `%20` or `+`.

You may also want to consider URL-encoding the `objectID` and `dir` parameters as well.

Incidentally, there is a typo in `conditon.Dir[0]`: should it be `condition` rather than `conditon`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between 2014-8-1 and 23:59:59 in your url string.(2014-8-31 23:59:59). That may cause the problem Url must not consist of white spaces.

"A URL must not contain a literal space. It must either be encoded using the percent-encoding or a different encoding that uses URL-safe characters"

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls)

You must encode white spaces