# Hover effect does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to implement a simple hover effect - it works lovely in Chrome but not in MSIE.  Is there an alternative?  Or a fix that will make this work in MSIE?  Most hover/rollover effects I've tried have this issue in IE.

[normalize.css](http://pastebin.com/qwPTVzgx)
[demo.css](http://pastebin.com/ghsEz4RX)
[set2.css](http://pastebin.com/zZkhy55H)
[font-awesome.min.css](http://pastebin.com/TutEFw0e)

**Markup - Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800,500,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style Library/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style Library/css/demo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style Library/css/set2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style Library/fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
</head>

<body>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="content">
                <h2>Goliath</h2>
                <div class="grid">
                    <figure class="effect-goliath">
                        <img src="Site%20Documents/23.jpg" alt="img23"/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>Thoughtful <span>Goliath</span></h2>
                            <p>When Goliath comes out, you should run.</p>
                            <a href="#">View more</a>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="effect-goliath">
                        <img src="Site%20Documents/24.jpg" alt="img24"/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>Thoughtful <span>Goliath</span></h2>
                            <p>When Goliath comes out, you should run.</p>
                            <a href="#">View more</a>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                </div>
        </div><!-- /container -->

    </body>
</html>
```

**Working correctly in Chrome (cursor hovered on the right panel)**
[image: Working correctly in Chrome (cursor hovered on the right panel)]

**In MSIE 11, not working :(** 
[image: in MSIE 11, not working :(]

Comment: Sigh, so many problems with "does not work in IE"... ever since IE7 this has been the bane of most web developers... Have you tried putting IE in edge mode? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` Also do you get any errors in the javascript console in IE or when you look at the CSS source?

Comment: can you direct us to a pen or the page so that we can inspect it?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets, edge mode didn't fix it - still seeing the issue.  No JS errors or when I look in the source using dev tools.

Comment: @Vandervals, sorry, the page isn't hosted publically anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put your markup through the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix all errors.  Internet Explorer especially dislikes invalid HTML markup and you have an unclosed `<div>` element among other things.
2. Your last `<link>` tag is missing its closing bracket, `>`.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style Library/fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
   ```
3. You have a whitespace character within the `href` URL of your CSS paths triggering W3C errors, `href="../Style Library/css/normalize.css"`. Try getting rid of that by renaming whatever it takes. [Play it safe and avoid whitespace within any URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442701/594235).
4. You never stated specifically which versions of Explorer.