# Access file using pre-signed url

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mule

I am adding an object to a bucket in Amazon S3. The addition is successful, now I want to make the file accessible to others by the pre-signed url.

The pre-signed url is of the form: 
`https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>?AWSAccessKeyId=<access key>&Expires=1432722343&Signature=mmfv%2Fddhhakla1csUrb%2FtRCXYu8%3D`

But when I try to load the url, it return with an error:

```
    <Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
         The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId></AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>
      GET 1432727995 /<bucket>/<key>
</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>mmfv/ddhhakla1csUrb/tRCXYu8=</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>
     47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 34 33 32 37 32 37 39 39 35 0a 2f 72 69 2d 73 65 72 76 69 63 65 2d 74 72 61 6b 2d 74 65 73 74 2f 74 65 73 74 53 75 6e 69 74 31 2e 78 6d 6c
</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>0E72b9858758353A0D906</RequestId>
<HostId>
    SOME VALUE
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Another Question:
If I have an URI that has '+' in it, how do I access the page using the URI  because trying the URI in the web browser turns it into space(" ") and that isn't correct?

Comment: For the uri "+" part of your question it is normal. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls

Comment: If a URL needs to represent a literal `+` it should be encoded as `%2B`.  A space, in turn, is encoded as `%20`.  On the signed URL, you aren't reusing the `PUT` URL to try to `GET` the object are you?  What code is doing the signing? One of the SDKs?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The url that is generated as the pre-signed url , I am trying to use that uri to access the file, where it gives me an error of signature not matching.

Comment: Are you calculating the signature yourself, using the Secret Key associated with the Access Key in the URL?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The pre-signed url is auto-generated, that contains the 'signature' param

Comment: Well, in that case it seems that the auto-generated signature is wrong. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html