# Bad URI on heroku when using HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, httparty, heroku-postgres

I currently am getting an the following error when using httparty on heroku.

HTTParty works for the first 11 times but on the 12th time it shows this error.

[image]

I am trying to seed data into my database.

When I go to the URL via my browser, it works. I ran the same code in development and it works. I am unsure what to do. Please help!

Comment: Looks like Heroku is rate limiting you.

Comment: Nope. It was the blank space. Like the answer below states.

Answer (score 1):

You pass invalid URI -

```
"https://maps.googlemaps.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=San Fransisco"
```

address has space in URI.

So, wherever you pass params, Do -

```
uri_path = https://maps.googlemaps.com/maps/api/geocode/json
params = {address: "San Fransisco",...............}

"#{uri_path}?#{params.to_param}"
```

Comment: How is the URI invalid? It works URL works in browser and in development?

Comment: parameter with space are not recognised by browser. Browser uses space by "+ or %20" like `https://maps.googlemaps.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=San%20Fransisco`. rails `to_params` method do that.

Answer (score 0):

Amit Suroliya was correct. I was using HTTParty as well and it was working through Curl and Development but would crash in production. Because the HTTParty parameter is the literal URL (as a string), it has to be a flawless URL/URI (meaning no spaces). My `bad URI` was as follows:

```
HTTParty.get("http://api.blahblahblah.com/v1/Boards/Search?&limit=79&query=#{query}&filter_date_from=1423353600")
```

Notice the interpolation `query=#{query}"`

So if `query='Michelle Obama'`, notice space between `Michelle` and `Obama`. Because of interpolation, the HTTParty.get('string') it is incorrect.

**Solution**:

Replace all whitespaces within your string with `+`, or you could use `%20`.

I used `query.gsub!(' ', '+')`

For more info on whitespace in the URL check it out here: [Spaces in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls)

Comment: Consider using only information that solves the question. Could everything before "SOLUTION" be deleted?