# java.net.URLEncoder#encode for Whitespace

Tags: java, url-encoding

`java.net.URLEncoder` will encode a single whitespace with `+`.

```
scala> val encodedSpace = URLEncoder.encode(" ", "UTF-8")
encodedSpace: String = +
```

However, per this W-3 [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), shouldn't it be encoded with `%20`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls

Answer (score 0):

From the DOCS (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4):

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:

1. Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced
   by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in
   [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by`
   %HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the
   ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF"
   pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A').
2. The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the
   document. The name is separated from the value by `=' and name/value
   pairs are separated from each other by`&'.

You have to replace it from `+` to `%20`. The prior is a default behavior.

For example:

```
System.out.println(java.net.URLEncoder.encode(" ", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"));
```

The above is the typical case of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

### In Summary:

`multipart/form-data` uses `MIME encoding`.

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` uses `+`.

`Properly encoded URIs` use `%20`.

### GET Submission:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=hello+world

### Resource with space in the name

http://camera.phor.net/cameralife/folders/2012/2012-06%20Pool%20party/