# Ember.$.param removes spaces from params and adds '+' sign

Tags: javascript, json

I am stuck with a problem. For instance if i have a json Object parameter like `param = {abc: 'my example parameter'}` and have an api like `var api = 'api/xyz?'`

now I want to append the parameters to my api, so I am using the following line of code

`var url = api + Ember.$.param(param || {});`

but the problem with this method is that when I use `Ember.$.param(param || {})` and if the param contains spaces it results in as `url = 'api/xyz?abc=my+example+parameter'` instead of `var url = 'api/xyz?abc=my example parameter'`

I know I can always right a custom function for this but I want to do it using the Ember's inbuilt functionalities, so is there any such Emberish way in which I can get the required api call without '+' in the parameter for spaces.

Comment: [urls shouldn't contain spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls), so [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) is encoding it correctly.  Either `+` or `%20` turns into a space, when the server decodes it

Comment: converting it into %20 is good enough but here the situation is it is converting it into +, and i don't want it to convert it into '+'

Comment: Why not?  Aren't you making a url?  `+` = space.  If it really matters, `Ember.$.param(param || {}).replace('+','%20')`;

Comment: but this would replace even '+' sign that incase I want to pass in the url.

Comment: You obviously haven't tried it, because `+` gets encoded to `%2B`