# hcm cloud rest call from jersey with query parameter having space

Tags: rest, jersey, query-string

i am trying to call a hcm rest end point using jersey

https:///resources/11.12.1.0/emps?q=FirstName like 'Astha'

I get the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:842)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.resource(Client.java:434)
..
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 93: https://<my-hcm-url>/resources/11.12.1.0/emps?q=FirstName like 'Astha'
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3072)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:840)
    ... 3 more
```

So I tried encoding the url

```
try {
    URL = URLEncoder.encode(URL, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:105)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:193)
......
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1080)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
```

Simple query parameters with '=' works fine withour encoding and all ..like /emps?q=FirstName='Astha'
But I want to use 'like' operator which requires space in the url. How to make it work ? Please help

I tried replacing the space with %20 and + as discussed in the [Spaces in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls). It did not work for me. It does not give any result.

The hcm rest end point api is available here https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/global-human-resources/r13-update17d/farws/Querying_a_Collection.html

Has anybody used this api earlier? If yes, how to call the below from java using jersey?

/resources/latest/emps?q=FirstName like 'Ki%'

Comment: I have updated the question with additional details. The answers given in the duplicate question did not work for me in my use case

Comment: If you “tried replacing the space” please update your code to show what you tried.

Comment: Found the problem
The problem is with the header. I need to add a header "REST-Framework-Version" with value 3. Once it is added, it worked.
<code>        
WebResource resource = c.resource(ENDPOINT_URL);
        String response = resource.queryParams(queryParams).header("REST-Framework-Version",3).get(String.class);
</code>