# Groovy JMeter Passing a string with spaces, avoiding %20

Tags: groovy, jmeter, url-encoding

I have an API which it's URL requires a string with spaces --> A B C 
I have tried

```
String X = "A B C";
vars.put("myKey",X);

GET  https://myserver.com/Api/v1.0/config/${myKey}
```

When JMeter executes this it replaces spaces with %20 in url.  I do not want JMeter to repalces spaces with %20, how can I do that

```
GET https://myserver.com/Api/v1.0/config/A%20B%20C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send [space in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls):

> A URL must not contain a literal space. It must either be encoded using the percent-encoding or a different encoding that uses URL-safe characters (like application/x-www-form-urlencoded that uses + instead of %20 for spaces).

But you can use `+` instead of space

And notice that server/receiving end will decode it back to spaces so there isn't a real issue.

Comment: @user3556956 can you give a link or explain which bug

Answer (score 1):

Usually browser replaces spaces entered into the address bar with `%20`. So do JMeter.

You have to update your API, so URL param with `%20` should be interpreted as a string with a space(s) by your API.