# Am not able to connect css to hml in visual studio code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

> I updated my vs code ide and i noticed that am not able to link my
>   html to css 
>       using intellisense i also installed a file path plugin but my css is still not 
>       connecting to my html.What alternative can be offered thaanks..
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Pokemon Games/css/Pokecss.css">
> ```

Comment: Are you sure you're entering the correct file path? What does your directory look like?

Comment: The directory written was gotten using the filepath intelisense plugin i installed never the less this is the full file path...(C:\Users\oluwatobi\Documents\html new\PRojects\Pokemon Games\css\Pokecss.css)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Pokemon\ Games/css/Pokecss.css">
```

If you're using a space, you need to use a special escape character `\`.

Do upvote me if it works!

Comment: It did not work, also removed the space from the folder name too, but i noticed that when i use operamini browser, the css file become active but the bootstrap design is not effective there do you know what is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space in your url `href="../Pokemon Games/css/Pok...` While having a space in the file formats on your home system works, using spaces in URI/URL addresses doesn't. If you really need that space in your URL, you can represent the space with `%20`, or simply use a hyphen `-`.

More discussions on this:
[Is a URL allowed to contain a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)
[Spaces in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls)
[Google on Spaces in Your URLs](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-spaces-in-urls-20820.html)