# Making a GET query with spaces

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I am writing an **iOS App** in Swift 4.2. I am using [Moya Networking](https://github.com/Moya/Moya).

I have to use below **GET** query for fetching  data from server:

> https://api.backendless.com/AABE5C4B-AA58-955C-FF16-27B64A185300/46FDFF59-CF95-B699-FFF5-83B681610700/data/quilt_detail?where=addedDate>1555515000
>   AND quitID='9FE17AA3-E182-6DFA-FF1D-52B33B2B8D00' AND
>   ownerId='AC1CB90D-CF3E-7243-FF87-9E408D68E800'&props=sleepHours,addedDay,addedDate

**My Code:**

```
var task: Task {
        switch self{
        case .getTrends(let quiltID, let addedDate, let ownerId):
            return .requestParameters(parameters: ["where":"addedDate > \(addedDate) AND quitID='\(quiltID)' AND ownerId ='\(ownerId)'", "props":"sleepHours,addedDay,addedDate"], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
        }
    }
```

But issue it, while executing it makes below **GET** Query:

> https://api.backendless.com/AABE5C4B-AA58-955C-FF16-27B64A185300/46FDFF59-CF95-B699-FFF5-83B681610700/data/quilt_detail?props=sleepHours%2CaddedDay%2CaddedDate&where=addedDate%20%3E%201556955782%20AND%20quitID%3D%276264A540-84F3-4D09-FF8D-00D4C94E9D00%27%20AND%20ownerId%20%3D%27DB64B524-8973-9357-FF67-3C69B6CD1C00%27
>
> Instead of:
>
> addedDate>1555515000 AND
>   quitID='9FE17AA3-E182-6DFA-FF1D-52B33B2B8D00' AND
>   ownerId='AC1CB90D-CF3E-7243-FF87-9E408D68E800'
>
> its making:
>
> addedDate%20%3E%201556955782%20AND%20quitID%3D%276264A540-84F3-4D09-FF8D-00D4C94E9D00%27%20AND%20ownerId%20%3D%27DB64B524-8973-9357-FF67-3C69B6CD1C00%27

How to make a GET query with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

URLs string never has spaces [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Your query **does** contain the spaces. They've just been **percent-encoded** or also known as **URL-encoded**. This is a mechanism to include characters in a URL that would otherwise not be legal or that would conflict with the URL structure. Learn more on [Wikipedia's percent-encoding article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

A simple example would be a GET param value that contains a `&`. You have to encode it otherwise the value after it would start a new param.

The server receiving the request will see the original data that you sent. You can verify this in your browser's console with the `decodeURIComponent`:

```
decodeURIComponent('addedDate%20%3E%201556955782%20AND%20quitID%3D%276264A540-84F3-4D09-FF8D-00D4C94E9D00%27%20AND%20ownerId%20%3D%27DB64B524-8973-9357-FF67-3C69B6CD1C00%27')
```

This returns:

```
addedDate > 1556955782 AND quitID='6264A540-84F3-4D09-FF8D-00D4C94E9D00' AND ownerId ='DB64B524-8973-9357-FF67-3C69B6CD1C00'
```