# configure urls in django, cmd prints: AttributeError: module 'myapp.views' has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, django

i have been trying to run this code but it doesn't show the "Hey, Welcome" in the `views.py`

`myproject/myapp/views.py:`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hey, Welcome</h1>")
```

`myproject/myapp/urls.py:`

```
urlpatterns=[
    path(" ",views.index, name="index")
]
```

`myproject/urls.py:`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),<br>
    path(' ', include('myapp.urls') ),
]
```

pls can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, when I run the code, it only shows 'the install worked successfully! congratulation!!' without running the html code that I pass in the `views.py`

Comment: why you have spaces in the quotes. remove the spaces.

Comment: Just remvoe space in uls path("",views.index, name="index"),  path('', include('myapp.urls')),

Comment: i also remove the spaces it and started afresh, its still shows the django template

Answer (score 0):

Please remove space from the url pattern.

myproject/myapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path("",views.index, name="index")
]
```

myproject/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path("",views.index, name="index")
    path('', include('myapp.urls') )
]
```

Comment: i also removed the spaces and started afresh but its still show the django template

Answer (score 0):

You are using space in path which result in this mess
Try removing those spaces

```py
path("",views.index, name="index")
```

```py
path('', include('myapp.urls')),
```

refer this for more clarity [Spaces in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls)