# Handling special characters in uri

Tags: java, spring, controller, spring-resttemplate

The below mentioned is my requestUrl
"http://localhost:80/v1/accounts/60a362bd6b84a37effc8f5a3/name/QA Analyst"
I am using the following code

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(requestUrl);
ResponseEntity<RoleResponse> responseEntity = null;
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity(RestUtil.getHeaders(this.appSecret));

try {
  responseEntity = this.restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, RoleResponse.class, new Object[0]);
} catch (Exception var9) {
  log.error("Error occurred while getting role by name for accountId {}", accountId, var9);
  throw new RestClientException("rest_client_exception", "Unable to get role by name for account");
}
```

In the service which is running on port 80 with java 8 version, I can see the following uri being hit
"v1/accounts/60a362bd6b84a37effc8f5a3/name/QA%2520Analyst"
but this uri is being handled and can get responsecode 200.
Now I migrated to java 17 and the request is throwing 400 BAD_REQUEST.
What is the reason and how can I handle this ?
The restTemplate I am using is of   org.springframework.web.client

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to have a space in your request URI. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls) on why a URL should not contain a literal space. I think the issue in your case is that the space character is being encoded twice. A space character gets URL encoded to `%20` and a `%` character is encoded to `%25`. Thus your URL gets encoded twice to `%2520`. I suspect that `builder.toUriString()` maybe encoding it once followed by another encoding in `restTemplate.exchange()`. I'm not sure but it is quite likely that one of the implementations changed in Java 17 and that is why it is a terrible idea and design to have a space in your URI. I would rather have it as a query parameter that ensures the safe encoding of most characters.

`http://localhost:80/v1/accounts/{accountId}?name=QA%20Analyst`

A good practice for RESTful API design is that path parameters are used to identify a specific resource, while query parameters are used to sort/filter those resources. In your case, it appears that you are doing a filtering/search by name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `fromHttpUrl()` method encodes url and then in `RestTemplate#exchange` your url is encoded twice.
So, try this:

```
  String uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:80")
                  .path("/v1/accounts/{accountId}/name/{roleName}")
                  .buildAndExpand("60a362bd6b84a37effc8f5a3", "QA Analyst")
                  .toUriString();

   System.out.println(uri); // not encoded yet: http://localhost:80/v1/accounts/60a362bd6b84a37effc8f5a3/name/QA Analyst

  responseEntity = this.restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, RoleResponse.class, new Object[0]);
```